# Why does not atom recommends/auto-completes console.log()?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

OK, I have started using atom text editor. I am both a beginner to atom text editor and to javascript. I wonder one thing, why Atom does not provide suggestions/auto-completes for the following case:

If I want to write a `console.log()` for example, typing `con` does not pop up any recommendation, even if I hit `ctrl+space`. Is this only related to Atom text editor, or is there something wrong in my understanding of `console.log()` and javascript? Actually I have tried in sublime and it also did not offer me completion for `con`.

Comment: consider filing an issue [over the repo](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/issues)

Comment: @Tibebes.M ok, so, it is not related to something I don't know, but it is a bug. I will do it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Completing to `console.log()` is already possible, you simply need to type `log`. This also also works with `warn` or `error`, but other console methods such as `time` / `timeEnd` or `trace` are not supported.

**Demo:**

[image]

To override this default behaviour, you can create [your own snippet](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/).

**Example:**

```coffee
'.source.js, .source.ts':     # defines the scope of the snippet, e.g. JavaScript and TypeScript
  'console.log()':            # the greyed-out part in the completion popup
    'prefix': 'console'       # trigger for the snippet
    'body': 'console.log($1)' # body of the snippet, where $1 is the cursor position after the completion
```